# Asking Jenkins to email a build notification on demand

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I found plenty of plugins that create notifications based on rules, but I couldn't find a plugin that could notify me when a given build is over.

For instance, I'd like to be able to press some button from an ongoing build page so that I'm notified (by mail for instance) when that build is over.

Is there an existing plugin that can do that?

Comment: Think that means setting environment-variables or similar for an already job. Don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Email-ext plugin allows you to add post build editable email notifications, and in the advanced settings you can set triggers.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: This is not what Vincent needs, email-ext notifications cannot be enabled through UI while the build is running.